# How to round number to two digits after the decimal place and have a comma separator?

Tags: formatting, calculations

I have the following function:

```
% Formats inputed number with 2 digits after the decimal place
\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[1]{\FPround{\cost}{#1}{2}\cost} %
```

`\cost` goes through some calculations before this.

Is it possible to change this so that it rounds to 2 digits after the decimal place and uses a comma as separator?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know about the possibilities with `expl3`? Can you show something more about these “calculations” before the usage of `\cost`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) provides a host of formatting options via [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). The following should suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\formatNumber}[2][]{\num[%
  round-mode=places,% Round output to specified number of places
  round-precision=3,% Round-precision is 3
  output-decimal-marker={,},% Use , as decimal marker
  #1% Other options
  ]{\calc{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\formatNumber{2*3/5+pi}% 4.342

\formatNumber[round-precision=1]{2*3/5+pi}% 4.3

\newcommand{\cost}{20}

\formatNumber{\cost+pi}% 23.142

\end{document}
```

> 4,342
>   4,3
>   23,142

Options can be set globally (via `\sisetup{<options>}`) or locally, as is done inside the options for `\num[<options>]`.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you load the `siunitx` package and create a dedicated macro, using the macro `\num` that's provided by the `siunitx` package, to achieve your formatting objectives. Note that rounding to two digits is performed automatically, as well as setting `,` (a comma) as the output decimal marker. As inputs, both `,` or `.` are OK as the decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\mynum}[1]{\num[output-decimal-marker={,},
                             round-mode=places,
                             round-precision=2,
                             group-digits=false]{#1}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\mynum{12345.6789}

\newcommand{\cost}{9876,5432}  % just for this example
\mynum{\cost}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the [`numprint`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint) package and its command `\nprounddigits{}`, which is switched off by `\npnoround`.

Default language of `numprint` is German, and so are its default typographical conventions. You can switch to the language specified in option of the `babel` package by using the `autolanguage` option. If `babel` is not loaded, the `autolanguage` option makes numprint opt for the English conventions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[np, autolanguage]{numprint}
\begin{document}
  \nprounddigits{2}
  \np{2.192}\quad\np{2.199}\quad\np{1.1853}\par
  \npnoround
  \np{1.1853}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, if you have inserted, for example, `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in the preamble of your document, the `autolanguage` option of `numprint` will make your document follow the French typographical conventions:

[image]

Up to now `numprint` supports German, English, French, Spanish, Portuguese and Dutch typographical conventions for numbers.

Comment: How would you enable the use of `,` as the output decimal marker?

Comment: @Mico By using the `\npdecimalsign{}` command, with you decimal marker as argument. The recommended way is to use the conventions of your document's language, however.