# Reduce the number of figures presented after the decimal point in a function

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have a function to report the results of a statistical test (ANOVA) in the correct format, which I had help in doing from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235482/function-to-autoformat-string-of-text%20/).

I now need to reduce the number of figures presented after the decimal point such that the F value (#3) is followed by 2. How can I do this without having to go through each instance I use the function and change this manually?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\def\anova(#1,#2,#3,#4){$F_{#1,#2}\!=\!#3$, $p\!=\!#4$}

\begin{document}

    The results are \anova (1,14,1.234,.001)

\end{document}
```

The end result should look like this – note that the p (#4) value does not have a 0 before the decimal point.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this question! The number of decimal points? Each number has a decimal point only. Do you mean the number of figures after the decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `siunitx` and its `\num` command, with appropiate settings depending on the desired formatting (see code example)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\anova(#1,#2,#3,#4){$F_{#1,#2}\!=\!\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{#3}$, $p\!=\!\num[add-integer-zero=false]{#4}$}

\begin{document}

    The results are \anova (1,14,1.234,.001)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify how the p value should be expressed.

Comment: @GeorgeVousden: See the update please