# How to format a number with a certain precision?

Tags: formatting

How do I change the precision of a number? The below example defines `\mynum` as a number with a large amount of digits. Most times when I use `\mynum` in the text I want it to be displayed exactly as defined, however I may sometimes wish to display it with 4 digits, so that in this example it would display as `12.35`.

Is there a package or pre-existing latex function to do this? Most stuff I can find about altering number precision refers to tables and column formatting, which doesn't apply to single numbers in text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mynum}{12.34567890}
\begin{document}
\mynum
\end{document}
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of this pseudo-code:

```
\round{4}{\mynum}    % not real code
```

Comment: `siunitx`'s `\num`/`\si` can do rounding. Not sure if it can deal with numbers defined via `\newcommand`.

Comment: Related/duplicate?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223831/how-to-round-number-to-two-digits-after-the-decimal-place-and-have-a-comma-separ

Comment: Very helpful, Steven. Thank you! It's close enough that I can work out the rest on my own.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @moewe and @Steven B. Segletes for the package suggestions and working examples. This is the solution I was able to put together.

Essentially, I was able to use the `\num` macro provided in the `siunitx` package along with some appropriate optional arguments to round numbers to whatever level of precision I liked. There are two ways I could go about this:

- Use `round-mode=places,round-precision=2` to round to 2 decimal places
- Or use `round-mode=figures,round-precision=4` to round to 4 significant figures.

Both methods change 12.34567890 to 12.35. My code is below, and also includes a macro in the form of the pseudo-code I wrote in my question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\mynum}{12.34567890}
\newcommand{\round}[2]{\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\mynum

\round{2}{\mynum}

\num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=4]{\mynum}

\end{document}
```

The output of this code is:

```
12.34567890
12.35
12.35
```